# How to get dropzone new file name

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I upload images via dropzone automatically and rename them during upload.
I need to get the new filenames so I can send to database.

I have tried this, but keeps giving error:

> Unexpected end of input

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    success: function( file, response ){
       obj = JSON.parse(response);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind got a solution, I tried this instead

```
 success: function( file, response ){
    console.log(response);
},
```